# Looking for a calculator module in joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, module, components, calculator

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5x25.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMHyP.png]

Hi!

I'm looking for a way to create a function that will do the following:

- When an option is checked, the price and image need to change.

I'm working with joomla and it would be awesome if there's a component or module for this. Perhaps it can also be made with javascript, but unfortunatly I don't have the knowhow to make it.

Options need to be manually added in joomla.

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: This question might be better received at https://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

For something out of the box, I used DM Easy Quote about two years ago and it worked well. https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/dm-easy-quote/  
If need something more complex, there is practically nothing you can't do with RSForms if you know a little javascript and/or PHP. https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html  They have quite a few tutorials you can check out for javascript functions.